# Multiple queries with multiple conditions store results in one row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I work on a project based on the calculation of log times.

My question is how to get one row from multiples queries to store final compiled result in one row?

My BDD Tables:

[image: Capture1]

And:

[image: Capture2]

My PHP Script:

```
$total_heures = array();
$total_pausette_ress1 = array();
$total_brief_r_ress1 = array();
$total_dej_r_ress1 = array();
//ALL DETAILS
$requete333="SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `in_time`,`out_time` ))  AS total_hours, in_time, out_time, pause_type, user_id
FROM rpconnect_attendance
WHERE status = 'pending'
AND MONTH(in_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`in_time`), user_id";
    $resultat1333= mysqli_query($con,$requete333);
                      $i = 0; 
                      while($rs3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultat1333)){
                            $bgi = ++$i % 2 ? '#f3f3f3':'#ffffff'; 
                    
                      $total_heures[$i] = $rs3;
                      }

$total_pausette1 = "SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `in_time`,`out_time` )) AS total_pausette1 , in_time, out_time, pause_type, user_id
                                                    FROM rpconnect_attendance
                                                    WHERE status = 'pending'
                                                    AND pause_type = 'pausette'
                                                    AND MONTH(`in_time`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`in_time`), user_id";
                $total_pausette_res1 = mysqli_query($con,$total_pausette1);
                  $j = 0;
                 while($total_pausette_r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_pausette_res1)){
                     $bgj = ++$j % 2 ? '#f3f3f3':'#ffffff';
                 $total_pausette_ress1[$j] = $total_pausette_r1;            
                
                 } 
                      
$total_brief1 = "SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `in_time`,`out_time` ))  AS total_brief1, in_time, out_time, pause_type, user_id
                                                    FROM rpconnect_attendance
                                                    WHERE status = 'pending'
                                                    AND pause_type = 'pausebrief'
                                                    AND MONTH(in_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`in_time`), user_id";
                $total_brief_res1 = mysqli_query($con,$total_brief1);
                $x =0;
                while($total_brief_r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($total_brief_res1)){
                    $bgx = ++$x % 2 ? '#f3f3f3':'#ffffff';

                $total_brief_r_ress1[$x] = $total_brief_r1;                   
                
                }
                    


$total_dej1 = "SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `in_time`,`out_time` ))  AS total_dej1, in_time, out_time, pause_type
                                FROM rpconnect_attendance
                                WHERE status = 'pending'
                                AND pause_type = 'pausedej'
                                AND MONTH(in_time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`in_time`), user_id";
                $total_dej_res1 = mysqli_query($con,$total_dej1);
                $p = 0;
                while($total_dej_r1 = mysqli_fetch_array($total_dej_res1)){
                    $bgp = ++$p % 2 ? '#f3f3f3':'#ffffff';
                $total_dej_r_ress1[$p] = $total_dej_r1;
                
                }

                      
foreach($total_heures as $t) {            
foreach($total_pausette_ress1 as $p) {
foreach($total_brief_r_ress1 as $b) {
    foreach($total_dej_r_ress1 as $d) {
        
   $temp_total = $t['total_hours'];
   $today = $t['in_time'];
   $user = $t['user_id'];
   $date_mois = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$today"));
   
   $temp_pause = $p['total_pausette1'];
   $temp_brief = $b['total_brief1'];
   $temp_dej = $d['total_dej1'];
   $inject_hour = "INSERT INTO `rpconnect_stockage`
                (`user_id`, `date`, `total_time`, `pause_time`, `brief_time`, `dej_time`)
                VALUES ('$user','$date_mois','$temp_total', '$temp_pause', '$temp_brief', '$temp_dej')" ;
                        $rassemblement = mysqli_query($con,$inject_hour);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that doesn't rely on screenshots of text.

Comment: Try JOIN-ing the rows inside your SELECT to get all values in a single row.